# ImageMagick SVG to PNG conversion - Path Edges Appearing Gray

Tags: svg, imagemagick, png

I'm using ImageMagick (v. 6.5.7) to create an PNG from an SVG.  I'm noticing that the path edges appear gray even though the path is created with a solid color.  I figured this was due to anti-aliasing so I turned that off:

```
convert +antialias box.svg  box__noantialias.png
```

but I get the exact same result.  Here is the result:

[image: grainy edge box]

Does anyone have any ideas on how to get around this?  Unfortunately, I'm limited to using ImageMagick so I don't have another option.

Here is the SVG if anyone is curious:

```
<svg height="150" version="1.1" width="730" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="overflow: hidden; position: relative;">
<desc style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);">Created with Rapha�l 2.1.0</desc>
<defs style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);"></defs>
<path fill="none" stroke="#ffff00" d="M146,46L148,46L149,46L151,47L152,47L154,47L155,47L156,47L156,47L157,47L158,47L158,47L159,47L160,47L161,47L162,46L162,46L163,46L164,46L164,46L165,46L166,46L167,46L168,46L168,46L169,46L170,46L171,46L172,46L172,46L173,46L174,46L174,45L175,45L176,45L178,45L178,45L179,45L180,45L181,45L182,45L184,45L186,45L187,45L189,45L192,45L193,45L194,45L196,45L198,45L200,46L202,46L203,46L205,46L208,46L210,46L210,46L211,46L212,46L214,46L214,46L215,46L216,46L218,46L220,46L221,46L222,46L224,46L226,46L228,46L229,47L231,47L234,47L236,47L236,47L238,48L243,49L244,49L246,49L246,49L248,49L248,49L249,49L249,50L249,53L249,55L250,59L250,61L250,64L250,68L250,71L250,75L250,77L250,81L250,85L250,86L250,91L250,91L250,97L250,99L250,101L250,104L251,105L251,106L251,109L251,109L252,111L252,112L252,113L252,114L253,117L253,118L253,119L254,121L254,123L254,125L254,127L254,127L254,128L254,129L254,130L255,131L255,131L254,131L254,131L248,131L242,131L236,131L230,131L224,131L222,131L219,131L214,131L210,131L205,131L202,131L198,131L198,131L196,131L194,131L192,131L187,132L184,132L181,133L178,133L176,133L172,133L169,133L164,133L161,133L158,133L156,133L153,133L150,133L148,133L145,133L144,133L143,133L142,133L142,133L142,133L142,130L142,127L141,122L141,118L140,109L139,105L138,101L138,99L137,97L136,93L136,91L136,87L136,85L136,83L136,81L136,80L136,77L136,75L136,74L136,72L136,71L137,69L137,68L137,67L137,66L137,65L137,63L137,62L137,61L137,61L138,59L138,57L138,57L138,55L138,54L138,53L139,53L140,51L140,50L140,49L140,49L140,49L140,48L140,47" stroke-opacity="1" stroke-width="8" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0)" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); stroke-opacity: 1; stroke-linecap: round; stroke-linejoin: round;"></path>
<path fill="none" stroke="#ffff00" d="M142,49L142,50L142,50L145,53L146,54L148,55L149,56L150,57L152,57L153,58L154,59L154,59L155,59L156,60L156,60L157,61L158,61L158,61L159,63L160,64L162,65L163,65L164,65L165,67L166,68L166,68L166,69L168,69L169,71L170,72L172,73L172,74L174,75L176,77L177,78L179,79L180,81L181,82L182,83L184,84L185,85L186,86L186,87L188,87L188,88L190,89L190,90L192,90L194,91L194,92L196,93L196,94L198,95L199,96L201,97L202,98L203,99L204,99L205,100L206,101L206,102L208,102L209,103L210,104L210,105L212,105L213,107L214,107L214,108L216,109L216,109L218,110L218,111L219,111L220,112L222,113L222,113L223,114L224,115L225,116L226,117L227,117L228,117L230,119L230,119L232,120L234,121L235,122L236,123L237,123L238,123L238,123L239,124L240,124L240,124L240,125L241,125L242,125L242,125L242,125L243,125L244,126L244,126L244,127" stroke-opacity="1" stroke-width="8" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0)" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); stroke-opacity: 1; stroke-linecap: round; stroke-linejoin: round;"></path>
<path fill="none" stroke="#ffff00" d="M242,49L242,49L241,49L240,50L240,51L240,51L238,52L238,52L238,53L236,54L236,54L235,55L234,56L232,57L232,58L230,59L229,59L228,60L226,62L224,63L223,64L222,65L220,67L218,69L216,70L216,71L214,72L213,73L211,75L210,77L208,79L207,79L205,81L204,83L202,83L202,85L200,86L198,87L197,88L195,89L194,90L192,91L190,93L188,93L187,95L186,95L184,96L182,98L182,99L180,99L180,100L179,100L178,101L176,101L176,102L176,103L174,103L174,104L173,105L172,106L171,106L170,107L168,109L168,109L167,109L166,110L166,111L165,111L164,111L164,113L162,114L162,115L161,115L160,115L160,116L159,117L159,118L158,118L157,119L156,119L156,120L155,121L154,121L154,122L154,123L152,123L152,123L152,124L150,124L150,125L149,125L148,126L148,126L147,127L146,127L146,128L146,128L146,129L145,129" stroke-opacity="1" stroke-width="8" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0)" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); stroke-opacity: 1; stroke-linecap: round; stroke-linejoin: round;"></path></svg>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few thoughts...

Your ImageMagick is old, it works fine with Version: ImageMagick 6.9.1-10, even without the `+antialias`.

I use the `rsvg` delegate rather than the `svg` one - I am not sure if that is making the difference.

[image]

If you can't upgrade for some reason, you can clean your image up with something like:

```
convert http://i.cubeupload.com/phlIj0.png -fill white -fuzz 50% -opaque gray result.png
```

Comment: I was using RSVG also.  I'm not sure if we'll be able to update our version of ImageMagick or not but it's helpful to know that this doesn't occur in newer versions.